# How do I redirect to a referring URL with hash values using JS?

Tags: javascript

Let's say a user navigates from *greatsite.com/uno#argument* to *coolsite.com/dos*. After some interaction on the second page, I need to send him back to his referrer with Javascript:

```
window.location = document.referrer;
```

The problem with running this is that `document.referrer` loses the hash values. The user gets redirected to *website.com/uno* without *#argument*. The page fails to work because its javascript depends on that argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about using the history ?

```
if (history.back() === undefined) location.replace(document.referrer);
```

Comment: This works ... even in IE6! Wow! My mind is blown! The laws of physics have been broken!

Comment: Just be sure to provide a fallback behavior in case there are no pages in the history.  For example, if your page was opened in a new tab.

Comment: That's strange when opening in new tab the document.referrer contains the hash, whereas if it's in the same window the hash isn't here

Comment: I used `history.length > 1` instead

Answer (score 0):

So link to dos, but append the current documents hash tag.. So dos#argument..

Then link to the referrer by appending the current hash tag to the referrer.

In other words, carry the hash tag with you through the pages.

Comment: Uno does not pass the hash to Dos because it could be written by another person.

Comment: Then use JavaScript, any time you change the hash, loop through all the links and change the JS on the hrefs to include the hash.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
window.history.go(-1)
```

but firefox may ask user whether to prevent